# Ruby on Rails Pagination: Sort order not respected (will_paginate gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, I'm sure there's a simple solution to my problem. Here is my `controller.rb` code:

```
@photos = Photo.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order => "date DESC", :per_page => 2
```

For some reason, my sort order is not being respected. Pagination is functioning correctly (such as the number per page) but the order is not working at all. I've tried using different values like `ASC` and `DESC` as well as different fields to no avail. Here is my entire controller function after moving "order" first :

```
def index
  @photos = Photo.all
  @photos = Photo.order("date DESC").paginate(:per_page => 12, :page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @gallery }
  end
end
```

I previously had this working perfectly in Rails 1, I just cannot figure this out with the will_paginate gem. As I mentioned, the `:per_page` parameter is working so I know the pagination is working, I'm just getting no sorting and no errors. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Which pagination gem are you using?

Comment: I'm using will_paginate

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @Philipe I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Phillipe asked you to look at the end of `log/development.log` in your application and find the database query that was generated as the result of `paginate` call. It will start with "SELECT ... FROM photos" and it will have a "LIMIT" clause.

Comment: You should share with us additional information: the will_paginate version, Active Record version, the type of database you're using (MySQL, Postgres, ...), and if you have some kind of `default_scope` in your Photo model (search for it).

Comment: Processing by GalleryController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mPhoto Load (1.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` ORDER BY date[0m
  [1m[35mPhoto Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT `photos`.* FROM `photos` ORDER BY date, date DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `photos` [0m
  Rendered gallery/index.html.erb within layouts/application (56.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 62.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)

Comment: @mislav Regarding additional information: I'm using MySQL, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2.9, will_paginate 3.0.4. My default scope is: default_scope :order => 'date'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem after answering some other user's questions. After reviewing my "Photo" model, at the request of @mislav I realized that it contained:

```
default_scope :order => 'date'
```

After removing this default_scope, ordering started functioning properly as it should. Problem solved.

Comment: That's only a workaround. See my answer for a true solution in cases when removing the `default_scope` clause isn't an option.

Answer (score 20):

You have a default order (by means of `default_scope`) which you can't override with the `order()` method, only append more ordering rules. You can reset the order, however:

```
@photos = Photo.reorder("date DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
```

BTW, you'll want to remove the `@photos = Photo.all` from the controller action. If you're fetching a paginated set of photos, it doesn't make sense to fetch them all from database first.

Comment: thank you! How did you know to use this? It's not in the rails documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Photo.per_page = 2
Photo.page(params[:page]).order("date DESC")
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't seem to work. It seems to just be sorting by date created (whereas "date" is a field that I would like to sort by).

Comment: Hmm, what I wrote is straight out of the docs.  Can you post some more of your class def for Photo?

Comment: I actually pulled mine straight off of the docs for the will_paginate function as well. I've updated my original post above with a more complete code section, let me know if you need more.